# Create docker image from Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

I have Artifactory, Docker, and Puppet. Is there a way to create a docker image from a jar file (or other binaries) from Artifactory? I haven't been able to find any examples of this anywhere.
Some documentation or external links or instructions how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a copy of [a Docker forum question (answered)](https://forums.docker.com/t/create-docker-image-from-artifactory/2238), feel free to go there for an answer.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: ya, I try all routes :) Thanks for the answer